# Jquery Tinyscrollbar plugin bug. Content area going out of borders

Tags: php, jquery, html, scrollbar

If you go to "Game rules" section and click around the sections "Backgammon, Narde, Nackgammon, Tavla, Old English" you will see that some sections load normally and the scrollbar works fine. Bigger sections like Backgammon and Narde do not load fully. The content in backgammon section is going out of the margin and the Narde section simply won't load fully.

What could be the issue here? All of the sections with scrollbar have the same identical settings. The only difference is that Backgammon and Narde sections have more text and more images. Could this be a reason for the glitch? Maybe the plugin somehow doesn't get to load all the content and already locks itself in place? What could be the possible solutions?

EDIT: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with tinyscrollbar plugin loading a bit too fast (before the inside content has loaded). What method could I use to put a timer on the plugin so it doesn't load as quickly or refreshes?

Answer (score 1):

first it seems that your "p" elements styles do not have width set to it and when rendered they hide behind the scroll bar making some of the text not visible.

This may not answer you question directly but it may have something to do with portions of text being hidden by overflow:hidden / overflow:scroll that is being used for the scroll bar.

You could also try using the jScrollPage plug in as it simplifies the scroll bar coding.

Comment: I removed all the <p> tags altogether, however the problem still persists. Some of the text goes out of the borders. This is really strange as it seems to work fine for sections like Tavla.

Comment: wrap it all in a span or a div and apply styles to it mainly width:540px or 520px try each which ever is closer for you

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. I think I need to set up some kind of timer for jquery tinyscrollbar plugin to refresh. Not sure how to do that. I think there's just too much content and it's loading too fast.